# How do you test lifecycle methods in Stenciljs

Tags: testing, stenciljs

I have a Stenciljs component with connectedCallback and disconnectedCallback lifecycle methods.  I want trigger these methods in test and verify their functionality.  How can I trigger these methods in either e2e or spec tests?

Note that I am trying to trigger connectedCallback without triggering componentWillLoad.  This implies that the component is created and connected once, disconnected and then reconnected.

[In the documentation](https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle#connectedcallback) it shows how this is done with a document object:

```
const el = document.createElement('my-cmp');
document.body.appendChild(el);
// connectedCallback() called
// componentWillLoad() called (first time)

el.remove();
// disconnectedCallback()

document.body.appendChild(el);
// connectedCallback() called again, but `componentWillLoad()` is not.
```

However, I cannot see how to do this with either newE2EPage or newSpecPage.  So the specific question is how can the functions described above be done with either of these two test pages.

Comment: The question is, should you? If you need to test the component, yes? But if the component is part of an app, the question becomes "Do I test the new wheels I just put on my car". Then it that view, the lifecycle methods are components themselves. Note: This _think in components_ is far from what everyone is doing today. Today and tomorrow we are still E2E testing **whole* applications instead of components. I bought a new car, should I E2E test it? E2E should be redefined, IMHO

Comment: As suggested above, you probably don't need to test the methods themselves. Instead, test what changes the lifecycle methods make. You trigger these methods by creating and destroying an instance of the component respectively.

Comment: Yes.  But the particular problem here is how to Trigger connectedCallback without triggering componentWillLoad.  This means that the component must be created, connected one time, disconnected and then reconnected.  So simply creating and destroying the component will not work.  I updated my question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Both newSpecPage and newE2EPage create a document-like object which means that your component will be instantiated and its creation lifecycle will be exercised including connectedCallback as well as componentWillLoad etc.

If you want to test individual methods alone, you could test an instance of the class object rather than the component instance:

```
new MyCmp().connectedCallback();
```

Depending on what this method does, this may not be a valid test or perhaps not work at all, since it is a plain object that you are testing not a living web component instance. So you may need to rethink your testing if this doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Yes, but where is this document object?  Can I access it and use it like the example in the main question?

Comment: Read the docs: https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing#example-end-to-end-test and https://stenciljs.com/docs/unit-testing#newspecpage